# Get module versions through wsadmin (WAS 8.5)

Tags: java, websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

How can I get the version of a specific module in a deployed application on a WebSphere 8.5 server?

I tried the following commands.

Get all installed applications:

```
wsadmin> $AdminApp list
MyApplicationEAR
```

Get version of this application (MyApplicationEAR):

```
wsadmin> $AdminApp view MyApplicationEAR -buildVersion
Build-ID of application:  SNAPSHOT_17-07-2014_16-33-28_rev_123
```

List all modules of this application:

```
wsadmin> $AdminApp listModules MyApplicationEAR
MyApplicationEAR#MyApplicationWeb.war+WEB-INF/web.xml
MyApplicationEAR#Toolbox.war+WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Get version of one module (MyApplicationWeb.war):

```
$AdminApp view MyApplicationEAR#MyApplicationWeb.war+WEB-INF/web.xml -buildVersion
WASX7015E: Exception while executing command: "$AdminApp view MyApplicationEAR#MyApplicationWeb.war+WEB-INF/web.xml -buildVersion". Exceptioninfo:
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7406E: The taskname buildVersion was not found in the application MyApplicationEAR.
```

But if I open the WebSphere admin console GUI (localhost:xxxx/ibm/console) and go to:

```
Applications >
  Application Types >
    WebSphere enterprise applications >
      MyApplicationEAR >
        MyApplicationEAR >
          Display module build IDs
```

I can see the own versions of all modules.

The version of the EAR is stored like the version of each module in the **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** under **Implementation-Version: XXX**.

Has somebody a hint, how to get these module versions with wsadmin (or with the Java AdminClient API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will just run the view command for the module, like  `$AdminApp view MyAppTestEAR#MyAppTest.war+WEB-INF/web.xml`, at the end of the output you will find `Build ID:  1.1`

```
wsadmin>$AdminApp view MyAppTestEAR#MyAppTest.war+WEB-INF/web.xml
MapModulesToServers: Selecting servers

Specify targets such as application servers or clusters of application servers
here you want to install the modules that are contained in your application. Mo
ules can be installed on the same application server or dispersed among several
application servers.
Also, specify the Web servers as targets that serve as routers for requests to
his application.
The plug-in configuration file (plugin-cfg.xml) for each Web server is generate
, based on the applications that are routed through.

Module:  MyAppTest
URI:  MyAppTest.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
Server:  WebSphere:cell=rad9vmNode02Cell,node=rad9vmNode02,server=server1

....  // cut off irrelevant output for short


ModuleBuildID: Module Build ID

Display module build IDs.

Module:  MyAppTest
URI:  MyAppTest.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
Build ID:  1.1
wsadmin>
```

**UPDATE**
You can actually run it on your application, you don't have to specify module:

```
wsadmin>$AdminApp view MyAppTestEAR -ModuleBuildID
ModuleBuildID: Module Build ID

Display module build IDs.

Module:  MyAppTest
URI:  MyAppTest.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
Build ID:  1.1
```

and to get available options you can run -tasknames

```
wsadmin>$AdminApp view MyAppTestEAR -tasknames
CustomActivationPlan
MetadataCompleteForModules
JSPReloadForWebMod
MapWebModToVH
SharedLibRelationship
AppDeploymentOptions
MapJaspiProvider
MapModulesToServers
MapResEnvRefToRes
ModuleBuildID
MapSharedLibForMod
CtxRootForWebMod
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Furthermore I've just found out with your basic help, that you can get rid of the other information with the command: `$AdminApp view MyAppTestEAR#MyAppTest.war+WEB-INF/web.xml -ModuleBuildID`! This will only print out 5 lines, which is not perfect at all, but even better than 200 lines ;)